How is ed25519 sc_reduce derived?
The supercop implementation of ed25519 features a function called sc_reduce that computes the modular operation a % l for a fixed big number l.
Here you can see the implementation:
https://github.com/floodyberry/supercop/blob/master/crypto_sign/ed25519/ref10/sc_reduce.c
How is that function derived? Is it a Barret reduction?

Well, it uses Montgomery...

Using Montgomery I don't get it. How you get it with Montgomery?

Montgomery modular reduction...

I know this reduction but I dont get the sc reduce result
